# Why 'Dial' application is not executed in this asterisk dial plans' context?

Tags: asterisk

I have this dial plan in the Asterisk config files:

```
[voicemenu-custom-1]
exten = s,1,NoOp(VM_Main)
exten = s,n,Answer()
exten = s,n,Goto(ringgroup,s,1)
exten = s,n,Dial(DAHDI/g1/009396464991)
exten = s,n,Hangup()
```

It's a very simple context in a dial plan, which asks the Asterisk to `Answer`, then to execute another context named `ringgroup` (to ring all the phones at the same time), then try to ring an external number (`009396464991`) and then hangup.

The code of the `ringgroup` context is:

```
[ringgroup]
exten = s,1,NoOp(RG1)
exten = s,n,Dial(SIP/1001&SIP/1002&SIP/1003&SIP/1004,30,${DIALOPTIONS})
exten = s,n,Hangup()
```

But what I get is that Asterisk answers the inbound call, then goes to the `ringgroup` context, but when it comes to the execution of the line `s,n,Dial(DAHDI/g1/009396464991)`, it encounters a dial error and won't execute `Dial` application.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could jump back to the `voicemenu-custom-1` Context, because you `HangUp`  (as already pointed out by arheops) after the Groupdial. 
You could jump to a Label, ie. "FwdOutbound" of `voicemenu-custom-1`, with `Goto(context,extension,label)`.

```
[voicemenu-custom-1]
exten = s,1,NoOp(VM_Main)
exten = s,n,Answer()
exten = s,n,Goto(ringgroup,s,1)
; Label
exten = s,n(FwdOutbound),Dial(DAHDI/g1/009396464991)
exten = s,n,Hangup()
```

`Goto` in the Ringgroup, instead of `Hangup`:

```
[ringgroup]
exten = s,1,NoOp(RG1)
exten = s,n,Dial(SIP/1001&SIP/1002&SIP/1003&SIP/1004,30,${DIALOPTIONS})
exten = s,n,Goto(voicemenu-custom-1,s,FwdOutbound)
exten = s,n,Hangup()
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the behavour you describe, I suggest you change your "Goto" into a "GoSub" and replace the "HangUp" in [ringgroup] with a "Return".  That will produce the effect you are looking for.

A "Goto" never comes back from the context you send it into.  It's a one-way ticket.  GoSub, as long as the call remains active (ie, not hung-up), will automatically return to the context it has been sent from as soon as it exhausts the new context.

Incidentally, GoSubs are considered the "better way" to do things than using macros now, so getting used to them is a good idea.

Further reading:  http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Gosub

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
asterisk -r 
core set verbose 10
```

to see what is gooing on.

In your plan I can see that you are dooing Goto(ringgroups,s,1) but context is ringroup, not ringroups.

Comment: Updated the question. A simple misspeling. :)

Comment: I don't understand what you triing to say. It NEVER go that line with g1 dialling. reason is simple - it do hangup at line 3 of ringgroup context.